# How to use presave hook to save a field value as node title?

Tags: nodes, 8, hooks, entities

I have a custom date field in a node type 'day'.
When the node is saved (or edited then saved), I would like to get the field_date value (not the published date) and save it into the title field.

I would like to know how, perhaps using a module to:

hook_presave

- GET FIELD VALUE
- SET TITLE AS FIELD VALUE
- SAVE NODE

Comment: [What's New in Drupal 8: Entity Field API](https://drupalize.me/videos/whats-new-drupal-8-entity-field-api?p=2075) skip to 4:20 if you want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to implement the [hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  switch ($entity->bundle()) {
    // Here you modify only your day content type
    case 'day':
      // Setting the title with the value of field_date.
      $entity->setTitle($entity->get('field_date')->value);
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you load the node when it is being passed into the hook as the `$entity` object?

Comment: Also, calling $entity->save() in a presave hook causes infinite recursion. This isn't a correct answer.

Comment: @JamieHollern You're right, the code had problems, now I edit with the correct answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

For entity of type profile i have used below code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'profile') {
    $zipcode = $entity->field_zip_code->value;
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$zipcode."&sensor=false";
    $details=file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($details,true);
    $lat=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $entity->field_geolocation->lat = $lat;
    $entity->field_geolocation->lng = $lng;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For entity of type user

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->field_uhid->value = 'testing';     //set value for field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to get and set the date field value using presave hook based on content type

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */

function YOUR_MODULE_global_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) 
{
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'blog') {
    $published = $entity->get('created')->value;
    $entity->set('field_published_date', date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $published));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter and save the title to any available field using Automatic Entity Label https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel